# Can't Add RegularExpressionValidator to Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm having an issue with programmatically adding a `RegularExpressionValidator` to any Container control (Panel, Placeholder, etc.). Here is my code:

```
// Get the path of the file on the server
string page = Page.Request.FilePath;
int managementCompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ManagementCompanyId_AddResident"].ToString().Trim());

// Get field validation details
Collection<ExportFieldValidation> details = ValidationBL.GetValidationDetails(managementCompanyId, page);

ContentPlaceHolder body = Page.Form.FindControl("ContentBody") as ContentPlaceHolder;

foreach (ExportFieldValidation detailItem in details)
{
    // Check if the control exists on the page
    TextBox control = body.FindControl(detailItem.FieldToValidate) as TextBox;

    if (control != null)
    {
        RegularExpressionValidator regex = new RegularExpressionValidator()
        {
            ControlToValidate = control.UniqueID.ToString(),
            ID = detailItem.ValidatorFieldName,
            ValidationExpression = detailItem.RegularExpression,
            Page = this,
            SetFocusOnError = true,
            Text = detailItem.ErrorMessage,
            Enabled = true,
            EnableViewState = true,
            CssClass = "Error"
        };

        Panel validationPanel = body.FindControl("PanelAddResident") as Panel;

        validationPanel.Controls.Add(regex);
    }
}
```

When I go to the page I get the error `Unable to find control id 'myControl' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'RegularExpressionValidatorResidentId'`, where my control is the `control.UniqueID.ToString()` from above, which we store in the database and is for sure correct, as I've double-, triple- and quadruple-checked the value.

However, if I replace `validationPanel.Controls.Add(regex);` with `Page.Form.Controls.Add(regex);` everything works perfectly.

Is there a way to add my validator to the container? I'm sure I'm just doing something wrong or missing a step in the middle somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This part is wrong:

```
ControlToValidate = control.UniqueID.ToString()
```

You need to use this:

```
ControlToValidate = control.ID;
```

You must provide an `ID` for control before.
`UniqueID` is the name the component will have in the client but Validator Controls use the server side control name to do this.

Comment: That's perfect! I swear I had already tried this, but I guess not. Figured it was something little. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `UniqueID` for javascript things where you can't predict the strange name generated controls will have. ;)

Comment: Makes sense, but can you give me a reason why it worked using UniqueID when I added the validator directly to the page?

Comment: I don't know exactly but depends on your markup your UniqueID and ID can end up beeing the same (if you are using ASP.NET 4).

Comment: It's .NET 3.5. And here's something weird that I had to do. This is database driven, so I needed to cover the case that the panel isn't on the page and add the validator to the form instead. In this case, I can't use `control.ID`. It gives me the same error as above. When binding to the page, I had to use UniqueID. When binding to the panel, just ID.